# What is the good choice for NodeJS Robotics Raspberry pi or Arduino?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, robotics

Actually, I'm very new to NodeJS and Robotics. I want to know which device is good for Nodejs Robotics before buying it.

Thanks

Comment: You can compare them here http://johnny-five.io/platform-support/

Answer (score 2):

I've used both. For the Arduino I needed to use Firmata and drive with an RPi, so I'd say a RPi.

A Raspberry Pi Zero is close to the size of an Arduino.